# Which one is the correct Plate Carrée projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I need to create a Plate Carrée map and I want to do so in QGIS. However I encountered a projection glitch in the Print Composer when I use `EPSG:32662`:

[image: Projection Glitch of Plate Carree [EPSG:32662] in QGIS Print Composer]

QGIS says that `EPSG:32662` is deprecated and [this gisSE answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25807/122597) suggests that also its successor `EPSG:32663` is outdated and that `EPSG:4087` replaced it. [Spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54001/) says that `ESRI:54001` is the "World Plate Carree". Neither of the last three can be found in QGIS' CRS settings. Simply using unprojected WGS84 / `EPSG:4326` doesn't look correct for my task.

Which one is the correct Plate Carree for QGIS and how can I set it?

Comment: A proj string for 32662 is [here](https://proj4.org/operations/projections/eqc.html).

Comment: why doesn't 4326 "look correct" - that is the usual Plate Carree projection

Comment: First of all, with `EPSG:4326` Positron disappears in QGIS 2.18.2 when I zoom out beyond ~ 1:75,000,000, depending on coordinates, often earlier. Secondly, in QGIS 3.2 it produces the weird glitch in the gif above (also, interestingly beyond a certain zoom level). The same is true for `EPSG:32663`. Thirdly, it's probably a philosophical topic: https://www.sharpgis.net/post/2009/02/06/Why-EPSG4326-is-usually-the-wrong-e2809cprojectione2809d

Comment: `EPSG:4326` has the proj4 string `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs` 
 (as opposed to "**latlong**") and QGIS specifies `Extent: -180.00, -90.00, 180.00, 90.00`. My custom CRS doesn't have an extent and I have the feeling that this is the reason why it doesn't glitch when the viewport/some coordinates leave that extent...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I might have found a bug in QGIS 3.2. In QGIS 2.18 LTS `EPSG:32662` works as intended. Since I wanted degrees as map units rather than meters I created my own CRS in `Settings > Custom Projections` with this proj4 string:

```
+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

PS.: This doesn't solve the glitch in QGIS 3.2's Print Composer when I set the element's extent to [-180,-90,180,90]...