# how to make the translation between latitude/longitude and screen pixels

Tags: coordinate-system

The earth is three dimension object while our screen is two-dimension.

So when we use the gis software to display the geographic data, how do they handle the translation between  latitude/longitude and screen pixels?

I know the projection which will translate the latitude/longitude to a two-dimension point. But what is the unit of the two-dimension point? Is it the 'pixel`?

---

Update:

To make this question clearer:

[image]

The rectangle is the screen view port(with size 800x600), and I know the center coordinate(65E,26N), then how to get the coordinate of the four corner?

Comment: Usually the unit is a meter.  This site contains (literally) [thousands of examples](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=projection+units) testifying to this (the link goes to only a few hundred of them).

Answer (score 2):

I'm asuming you are talking of how GIS softwares show data with Lat Long on a Flat map, like this: [image: map]

Al the GIS Software that I have worked with, inlcuding ArcGIS & Qgis, treat the latlong as linear units, and show the data in [pseudo Plate Carree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) projection.

Now that I think of it, this question seems an exact duplicate of [Projecting EPSG:4326 data in 2D map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21352/how-is-epsg4326-data-projected-in-a-2d-map)
Does it answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, your answer is helpful. In fact, I want I am building an android application which will render the vector data with styling. Then once the map center is given, and I can get the viewport size, then I have to get the lngat coordinate of the four corners. And Then get the data and change them to screen pixel. That is why I ask this question. Then I wonder if the projection is necessary in my requirement?